# Silverlight WIA Scanning Class Data Type questions

Tags: c#, silverlight, wia

I realize there are a lot of questions out there about WIA scanning in C#, but there aren't as many related to Silverlight.  I've been following through some code here:  http://ithoughthecamewithyou.com/post/Scanning-from-the-ADF-using-WIA-in-C.aspx 
And I understand what's going on, except that I don't understand where the "Device", "Item", "Property" data types are coming from.  No one seems to include their using statements, and being new to C# and silverlight, I'm confused.

I found another question here: [WIA Scanning via Feeder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077020/wia-scanning-via-feeder) that also uses those data types, but I still can't seem to figure out why when I try to use them they can't be found anywhere in the namespace.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any (free) Silverlight assembly that you can reference in order to talk to WIA. You can make use of the COM objects WIA provides, by using COM Automation. Pete Brown has written a very helpful [article](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/14/scanning-an-image-from-silverlight-4-using-wia-automation) showing how to do this. I've also [blogged](http://andrewolson.wordpress.com/2011/10/19/adf-scanning-with-silverlight/) about my experiences with writing a Silverlight app that uses WIA to talk to a scanner that has a document feeder.