# Wia code won`t work with kodak scanmate i1120 scanner

Tags: vb.net, wia

I have re-written a program that scans a document and reads a barcode from the document that was written in vb6 and worked on windows xp.

This new program works fine on windows 10 with an old fujitsu fi-4129c2 scanner but I cant get it to work with a new scanmate i1120 scanner.

The error I get is on the following line :

```
MyImage = DirectCast(ConnectedScanner.Items(1).Transfer(WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatBMP), WIA.ImageFile)
```

and the error I get is :

[image: Scan Error]

I know that the code works as I have it working with the fujitsu scanner but I cant seem to figure out what value is giving me the error on the scanmate.

I have just tried it with the following three lines of code only and it still gives me the same error :

```
Dim CD As New CommonDialog
Dim F As ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType)
F.SaveFile("C:\Temp\WIA." + F.FileExtension)
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you? - Is `ConnectedScanner.Items(1)` a valid object? Does the scanner support that transfer format?

Comment: The ConnectedScanner shows as a valid object. do you know how I would find out if the scanner supports a given transfer format.

Comment: Does the OLD program work with the new scanner? If not, it only supports twain, not wia. Usually the specifications will tell you the supported interfaces.

Comment: just posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the WIA_DPS_PAGES setting for the scanner.

I tried changing it using the following code :

```
With ConnectedScanner.Items(1)
        .Properties("3096").Value = 1
        .Properties("6146").Value = 2 
        .Properties("6147").Value = 300 'dots per inch/horizontal
        .Properties("6148").Value = 300 'dots per inch/vertical
        .Properties("6154").Value = -50 'brightness
        .Properties("6155").Value = -50 ' contrast
    End With
```

But this didn`t work so after a look at [WIA Scanning via Feeder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077020/wia-scanning-via-feeder)

I converted the code on this page to vb and used the following Sub :

```
Public Sub SetDeviceProperty(device As Device, propertyId As Integer, value As Object)
    Dim [property] As [Property] = FindProperty(device.Properties, propertyId)
    If [property] IsNot Nothing Then
        [property].let_Value(value)
    End If
End Sub
```

And changed the settings using :

```
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 3096, 1)
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 6146, 2)
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 6147, 300)
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 6148, 300)
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 6154, -50)
SetDeviceProperty(ConnectedScanner, 6155, -50)
```